# ElasticSearch custom analyzer breaks words containing special characters

Tags: elasticsearch

If user searches for `foo(bar)`, elasticsearch breaks it into `foo` and `bar`.

What I'm trying to achieve, is when a user types in say, `i want a foo(bar)`, I match exactly an item named `foo(bar)`, the name is fixed, and it will be used by a filter, so it is set to a keyword type.

The approximate steps I did,

1. define a custom analyzer
2. define a dictionary containing `foo(bar)`
3. define a synonym mapping containing `abc => foo(bar)`

Now, when I search for `abc`, elasticsearch translates it to `foo(bar)`, but then it breaks it into `foo` and `bar`.

The question, as you may have guessed, is `how to preserve special characters in elasticsearch analyzer?`

I tried to use quotes(") in the dictionary file, like `"foo(bar)"`, it didn't work.

Or is there maybe another way to work around this problem?

By the way, I'm using `foo(bar)` here just for simplicity, the actual case is much more complicated.

Thanks in advance.

---- edit ----

Thanks to @star67, now I realized that it is the issue of the tokenizer.

I am using the plugin `medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-ik`, which provides an `ik_smart` tokenizer, which is designed for the Chinese language.

Although I realized what the real problem is, I still don't know how to solve it. I mean, I have to use the `ik_smart` tokenizer, but how do I modify it to exclude some special characters?

I know that I can define a custom pattern tokenizer like this as @star67 provided:

```json
{
  "tokenizer": {
    "my_tokenizer": {
      "type": "pattern",
      "pattern": "[^\\w\\(\\)]+"
    }
  }
}
```

But I also want to use the `ik_smart` tokenizer, because in Chinese, words and characters are not separated by space, for example `弹性搜索很厉害` should be tokenized as `['弹性', '搜索', '很', '厉害']`, words can only be split based on a dictionary, so the default behavior is not desirable. What I want is maybe something like this:

```json
{
  "tokenizer": {
    "my_tokenizer": {
      "tokenizer": "ik_smart",
      "ignores": "[\\w\\(\\)]+"
    }
  }
}
```

And I couldn't find an equivalent setting in elasticsearch.

**Is it that I have to build my own plugin to achieve this?**

Comment: can you share your custom analyzer definition ?

Comment: @Amit-ESenthusiast I realized now that it is the tokenizer's problem thanks to star67. It's not the problem of analyzer's definition. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use another [tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/analysis-tokenizers.html) in your custom [analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/analysis-analyzers.html) for your index.

For example, the `standard` tokenizer (used via analyzer for short) splits by **all non-word characters** (`\W+`):

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": "foo(bar)"
}

==>

{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "foo",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "bar",
      "start_offset" : 4,
      "end_offset" : 7,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Compare to a custom tokenizer, that splits by **all non-word characters except** the `(` and `)` ( which is `[^\w\(\)]+`):

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "[^\\w\\(\\)]+"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST my-index-000001/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "foo(bar)"
}

===>

{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "foo(bar)",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I used a [Pattern Tokenier](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html) as an example to exclude certain symbols (`(` and `)` in your case) from being used in tokenization.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am using the `medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-ik` plugin, for the Chinese language, which provides a `ik_smart` tokenizer. I didn't fully understand the underlying mechanism of elasticsearch. I thought that the tokenizer tokenizes a phrase base on the dictionary I have provided. Thank you very much the answer, I'll update the question. Thank you.